# Bootstrap is not working in Angular project

Tags: angular

[image]

I have made changes in Angular.json file added bootstrap path in Style array. still bootstrap is not working after running application.

Comment: important, you need to stop and restart `ng serve` also do you see the .css file getting loaded in the network tab? do you see any errors?

Comment: Yes I restarted my application with ng serve several time, and i am not able to see any error in console, and network tab, still its not working for me.

Comment: there should be one file called `styles.css` in the network tab. if you inspect it you should see somewhere the bootstrap css

Comment: Did you install bootstrap? Run npm install bootstrap. Restart the application and it should work.